# Java compiling error in NetBeans

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a JFrame in Java under Mac OS X 10.9.2 and I get this compiler error:

> java[12198:d07] Can't open input server
>   /Library/InputManagers/CTLoader

It happens when I am using JFrame or Frame...

Comment: Google is your friend: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5285558?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupted java installation. Try installing a new one:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp